# Registering an Azure Active Directory Application using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to register an Azure Active Directory application in Azure, using Powershell commands. It works well when I use Powershell on my laptop, but when I use the same command in Azure DevOps Release pipeline (inside Azure Powershell task), it fails. What can be the reason?

I have tried the following:

1. It works well when I run the command in local powershell (on my local machine)
2. I tried the same command in Azure DevOps with different Powershell versions (there is a field for specifying this in the Azure Powershell Script task), but it fails.

> $appName = "MyApplication" $appURI =
>   "https://myapplication.azurewebsites.net" $appHomePageUrl =
>   "https://myapplication.xxxxx.nl" $appReplyURLs = @($appURI,
>   $appHomePageURL, "https://localhost:12345") $myApp =
>   New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName -IdentifierUris $appURI
>   -Homepage $appHomePageUrl -ReplyUrls $appReplyURLs

Following is the error messages that I get:

> 2019-07-29T18:22:10.1100918Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name
>   C:\Modules\az_1.0.0\Az.Accounts\1.6.0\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
>   2019-07-29T18:22:17.0434281Z ##[warning]Both Az and AzureRM modules
>   were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be
>   imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook. If
>   you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use
>   the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your
>   machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none
>   of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information
>   can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
>   2019-07-29T18:22:25.8019093Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
>   2019-07-29T18:22:27.9638440Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope
>   CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
>   2019-07-29T18:22:28.5285827Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount
>   -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud
>   2019-07-29T18:22:30.4391614Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId
>
> ######## -TenantId *** 2019-07-29T18:22:30.9129390Z ##[command]& 'd:\a_temp##############.ps1'  2019-07-29T18:22:33.6730996Z
>
> ### [command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop 2019-07-29T18:22:33.8889503Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
>
> -ErrorAction Stop 2019-07-29T18:22:34.4461613Z **##[error]The term 'New-AzureADApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again**. 2019-07-29T18:22:34.7040074Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure
>   PowerShell script: Register an AAD app and generate credential for the
>   same

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an issue related to the documentation, the Azure Powershell Task is asking for the module version, **not** the powershell version.

Commentor here suggests trying 1.0.0 :

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4850